# How to get "week commencing" with AMPscript based on a given date

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Hope you're having a great day!

I'm referencing a specific date `DD/MM/YYYY` (New Zealand date format) provided from Sales Cloud as part of an automated email journey for contacts experiencing product delays. This date is an estimated delivery date from a supplier. However, to help manage expectations and allow for delivery wiggle room, I would like to present the contact with a week commencing date derived from the provided date as below:

Data Extension: `15/06/2021`

Email presents: "Our current best estimate is the week commencing `Monday, June 14, 2021`"

At present, I'm simply using the FormatDate function on the existing date without any logic to get the desired W/C date value. I've taken a look over the similar questions which arrived at answers making use of `NOW()` to get the current date but I was wondering if similar logic could be applied where the W/C date is calculated from a given future date.

The answers from Adam and Gortonington have certainly helped inspire the above with their answers to these questions:

- [How can we generate the “day of year” or “week of year” in
  ampscript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263356/how-can-we-generate-the-day-of-year-or-week-of-year-in-ampscript?rq=1)
- [Calculating the last day of next month using Ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124068/calculating-the-last-day-of-next-month-using-ampscript?rq=1)
- [Using AMPScript to output Current Month or following Month dependent
  on the day of the month in a Marketing Cloud Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316216/using-ampscript-to-output-current-month-or-following-month-dependent-on-the-day?rq=1)
- [Get first and last day of the week in Ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280316/get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-ampscript)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to suggest the same approach as the one in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280316/get-first-and-last-day-of-the-week-in-ampscript) post you linked. Just switch out NOW() for your delivery date.

Comment: Baneen! Hey. I was hoping it would be that simple, I swapped that out for the dynamic date and kept hitting validation issues. Possibly just a data issue. Will take another look at it again this afternoon. Great to hear from you, btw! :)

Comment: Likewise, nice to see you're still using Marketing Cloud, hope you're enjoying it! Probably is some kind of data issue, were the error messages very descriptive?

Comment: Descriptive? Never :p